# Change Eclipse welcome screen to another tool platform

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-jdt

I installed Eclipse for C++ developers. So the welcome screen is “Welcome to the Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers”. Later I added Java Development Tools. How can I instruct Eclipse to show Eclipse IDE for Java welcome screen instead of C++? Can I make it different for different workspaces?